# Forward a specific range of arguments in a variadic function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

Is there a way to *std::forward* a specific range of arguments in a variadic function? For example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
    void test_simple(T v0,T v1)
{
    std::cout<<v0<<","<<v1<<std::endl;
}

template<typename... TARGS>
    void test_variadic(TARGS ...args)
{
    test_simple(std::forward<TARGS>(args)...); // Forward all arguments except for the first one?
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    test_variadic(5.f,2.f,7.f);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I want *test_variadic* to forward only the last two arguments to *test_simple*, so that the output would be "2.0,7.0".

Comment: Do you want to drop first argument, or forward the 2 lasts ? (same with 3 arguments, but not with other numbers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an additional template parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
void test_variadic(T&& arg, Ts&&... args) {
    test_simple(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

That way, the first parameter is not part of the variadic.